# Unable to connect to bybit websocket (Getting an error: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1076))

Tags: python, api, ssl, websocket

I am trying to connect to a websocket api, bybit's websocket for the ones that are interested. I tried everything and read every documantation I could find, it's still giving me and Error:

> [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1076)

My code looks as followed:

```
import websocket

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    ws.send("{'op': 'subscribe', 'args': ['orderBookL2_25.BTCUSDT']}")

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(url="wss://stream-testnet.bybit.com/realtime_public",
                            on_message=on_message,
                            on_error=on_error,
                            on_close=on_close,
                            on_open=on_open)
ws.run_forever()
```

I anyone knows what the problem is or could be, please tell me/helm me, I have been banging my head agains the wall for the past 2 days because of this.
Thanks in advance :)